# apache won't set session

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, osx-mavericks

On my mac, i installed xampp. for some reason my localhost site i'm developing refuses to set sessions.

in my php.ini located at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc` i have this

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler=files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"

session.save_path="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp"
```

i've checked the `/temp` folder and the permission is set to 777

then i type `php -i |grep session.save` in my terminal i get this

```
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
```

any idea why i can't set sessions?

Comment: What does your phpinfo() say? Is the path to php.ini is the "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc" folder you mentioned?

Comment: @mohdyusuf it says loaded configuration file: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini